# clear workspace of GUI matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, variables, workspace

I have a **new** button in my GUI here is its callback:

```
function ptlNew_ClickedCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)  
% hObject    handle to ptlNew (see GCBO)  
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB  
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)  
cla(handles.axes1,'reset');  
clear variables
```

but the last line doesn't work
what can I do to clear workspace of my GUI without closing it to feed up memory?
my variables are in handles structure
for example if I have variable X, I should access it in form handles.X
I made my variables properties of handle because I wanted to access them in more than one callback function and I didn't want to make them Global

Also I tried to clear a specific variable. so instead of **clear variables** I used this line of code
    clear handles.FiducialPixels
But it doesn,t work too and when I try to access it in the next line by code:
    handles.FiducialPixels
it is printed on the Command Window quitely as it was before
I'm really confused what can I do?
The interesting issue is that line **clear variables** or **clear  handles.FiducialPixels** don't make any error or warning but they do their task!

As Li-aung Yip answered I changed the call back to this form:

```
function ptlNew_ClickedCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
names = fieldnames(handles);
rmfield(handles,'FiducialPixels');
names = fieldnames(handles)
handles.FiducialPixels
```

but this is what appeares on the command line running lines 4 and 5:

names =

```
'figure1'
'pnlControlPointsImageCoordinates'
'uitoolbar1'
'pnlCalculateParameters'
'mnuInteriorOrientation'
'btnLoad2'
'edtImageFile'
'text17'
'edtInteriorOrientation'
'edtF'
'text16'
'edtYPPA'
'text15'
'edtXPPA'
'text14'
'text13'
'btnBrowseLensDistortion'
'edtLensDistortion'
'text12'
'btnBrowseInteriorFile'
'text11'
'axes2'
'uitoggletool3'
'uitoggletool2'
'uitoggletool1'
'ptlNew'
'txtCalculation'
'btnJumpTo'
'btnLoad'
'edtImagePath'
'text9'
'btnSaveParameters'
'btnCalculate'
'edtNumber'
'text8'
'uitable1'
'btnGinput'
'btnBrowse'
'edtFilePath'
'text1'
'btngrpTypeOfOrientation'
'axes1'
'mnuItemControlPointsImageCoordinates'
'mnuItemCalculateParameters'
'rdbtnProjective'
'rdbtnAffine'
'rdbtnConformal'
'output'
'TableData'
'TableDataEmpty'
'Matrix'
'FiducialImageCoordinates'
'dataH'
'FiducialPixels'
'flag'
'X'
```

592 handles.FiducialPixels

ans =

1.0e+003 *

```
7.5294    3.8246
0.1357    3.8723
3.9200    0.2311
3.8882    7.4499
7.4817    0.2311
0.2152    7.5294
0.2311    0.2311
7.4658    7.4817
```

You see handles.FiducialPixels still exists
Even if you use **guidata(hObject,handles)** after the third line, the result will be the same

Comment: Can you clarify which variable it is you want cleared -- all? X? handles? You can clear individual variables with clear var_name. Also, can you clarify what you mean by "the last line doesn't work."

Comment: I want to clear all variables that I made in my program even if they are in handle structure( because you know handle structure has some other members like tags of your buttons and their other properties,I don't want these variables be cleared because that way my GUI will be cleared)but variables that I created to do some calculations and processing should be cleared.I mean **clear variables** as the last line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to delete absolutely *every* workspace variable, including all workspace (global) variables created by your script, *and* those variables created at the command prompt *and* those variables created by other scripts, just use:

```
clear
```

Using `clear` (every variable) is considered impolite, though. This is because a user might be doing some work on the command line before calling your script. When your script calls `clear`, all of his work is erased (forever!)

---

If you want to delete `handles.FiducialPixels` - that is, a particular element of the `handles` struct - then `clear` is not what you want. Instead, use the [`rmfield()` function](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/rmfield.html), which is designed for deleting fields from structs.

Homework: read the documentation pages for [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html), and the functions for dealing with structs: `cell2struct | deal | fieldnames | getfield | isfield | isstruct | namelengthmax | orderfields | rmfield | setfield | struct2cell | substruct`.

---

Edit(1): `rmfield()` *does* work. You are just not using it correctly.

```
>> figure
>> handles.h1 = uicontrol

handles = 

    h1: 329.0011

>> handles.h2 = uicontrol

handles = 

    h1: 329.0011
    h2: 0.0016

>> handles = rmfield(handles, 'h1')

handles = 

    h2: 0.0016
```

From `doc rmfield`:

> **`rmfield`**
>
> Remove fields from structure
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `s = rmfield(s, 'fieldname')`
>
> `s = rmfield(s, fields)`
>
> **Description**
>
> `s = rmfield(s, 'fieldname')` removes the specified field from the
>   structure array `s`.
>
> `s = rmfield(s, fields)` removes more than one field at a time. `fields`
>   is a character array of field names or cell array of strings.

Note that the calling convention `s = rmfield(...)` indicates that `rmfield` *returns* something. In this case, the original structure `s` **is not modified**. Instead, `rmfield()` returns a **new** struct, without the fields you specified for deletion.

Comment: That's because you didn't read the documentation for `rmfield`. See above.